# Collapse objects in array based on id and calculate new properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-wrangling

Here's a sample of a very particular dataset I am working on. I have an array of objects in the following format:

```
const input = [
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "South", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "b", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "c", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "South", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "South", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "b", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "c", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "East", category: "c", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "02", country: "Turkey", region: "North", category: "a", value: "15", population: "25"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "02", country: "Turkey", region: "North", category: "b", value: "5", population: "25"}
]
```

How can I collapse the objects in the array based on `year` and `id` and create `a`, `b`, `c` and `total_population` new properties in **output** based on the data in `category`, `value` and `population` from **input**?

One thing to note is that `a`, `b` and `c` are cumulative sums and `total_population` is a cumulative sum based on `region`. This means that `population` values are duplicated i some cases (i.e.: there are three entries in country "India" and region "North" that should total 100 and not 300.)

```
const output = [
  {year: "2010", id: "01", country: "India", a: 20, b: 10, c: 10, total_population: 200},
  {year: "2015", id: "01", country: "India", a: 10, b: 10, c: 20, population: 300},
  {year: "2015", id: "02", country: "Turkey", a: 15, b: 5, population: 25}
]
```

My best attempt follows. Unfortunately I am constantly getting NaN when trying to execute the cumulative sum. Also, it seems that this solution does not perform well when testing it in a larger dataset.

```
const years = [...new Set(input.map((d) => d.year))].sort()

const country_ids = [...new Set(input.map((d) => d.country_id))].sort()

const combined_ids = {
  let array = [];

  country_ids.forEach((y, i) => {
    years.forEach((m) => {
      let obj = {};
      obj["year"] = m;
      obj["country_id"] = y;
      obj["combined_id"] = m + "-" + y;
      array.push(obj);
    });
  });

  return array;
}

const output = combined_ids.map((y, i) => {
  input.map((m) => {
    if (y.combined_id === m.year + "-" + m.country_id) {
      y.country_id = m.country_id;

      y[m.category] += !m.category
       ? 0
       : m.value === NaN
       ? 0
       : m.value === null
       ? 0
       : m.value === undefined
       ? 0
       : m.category === undefined
       ? 0
       : +m.value;

      y["total_population"] += +m.population;
      }
  });
  return y;
});
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of your attempt using the `[<>]` snippet editor. This code is invalid: `const combined_ids = {
  let array = [];`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below solution using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). First you need to create a dictionary to store unique population values. Then you can use another `reduce` to group objects and combine them together. `delete` will be used to make sure population for the same key is only used once:

```js
const input = [
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "South", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "b", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2010", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "c", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "South", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "South", category: "a", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "b", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "North", category: "c", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "01", country: "India", region: "East", category: "c", value: "10", population: "100"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "02", country: "Turkey", region: "North", category: "a", value: "15", population: "25"},
  {year: "2015", country_id: "02", country: "Turkey", region: "North", category: "b", value: "5", population: "25"}
]

let getKey = obj => `${obj.year}-${obj.country}-${obj.region}`;

let populationDict = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[getKey(cur)] = +cur.population;
    return acc;
}, {})


let output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    let { year, country_id, country, category, value } = cur;
    let val = +value;
    let prev = acc.find(x => x.year === year && x.id === country_id && x.country === country);
    let population = populationDict[getKey(cur)];
    delete populationDict[getKey(cur)];
    
    if(!prev){
        acc.push({year,id: country_id,country, [category]: val, total_population: population});       
    } else {
        prev[category] = prev[category] ? prev[category] + val : val;
        if(population) {
          prev.total_population += population;
        }        
    }

    return acc;

}, []);

console.log(output);
```